# Cloudfront with custom origin and identical domain

Tags: amazon-cloudfront

Let's say a website with the domain www.example.com is hosted on a LAMP server of a webhoster, which is not Amazon. The domain is managed by Route53.

Is it possible to somehow keep all settings on the LAMP webserver and still use www.example.com as the domain for Cloudfront? Like:

```
Client -> www.example.com -> Cloudfront Edge Server -> Custom origin available over www.example.com on LAMP webserver of third party webhoster
```

**Basically, I want to use www.example.com for both the Cloudfront Edge Server and the LAMP server.**

Best regards

Comment: This may be possible depending on exactly what the scenario is. You could have Route53 point www.example.com to CloudFront and have your origin server respond to both origin.example.com and www.example.com. Normal requests to www.example.com would be served via CloudFront. CloudFront would use origin.example.com as the origin. Then using something like a hosts file entry you could still have a dev team (for example) send traffic directly to the server with the host header of www.example.com. Would this meet your requirements?

Comment: No, this doesn't meet my requirements. Ideally www.example.com points to the Cloudfront Edge Server. And, the Cloudfront Edge Server has something like an `/etc/hosts`, where I can specifiy the A and AAAA records of the LAMP server.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot do anything like `/etc/hosts` on CloudFront -- it always uses public DNS to resolve the origin.

However, you can still do what you are trying to do -- but you just need to understand *why* this solution is indeed what you want, because it will seem like it is not (as you indicated in comments).

In Route 53, create a new A record for a new hostname for the origin server, such as origin.example.com.  **You do not configure this value anywhere on your origin server at all.**  Your origin server still believes it is www.example.com.

In Route 53, create an alias A record www.example.com pointing to origin.example.com.

At this point, your site works exactly as you expect and require.  The hostname "origin.example.com" is in the resolution path, but this information is invisible and unknown to the origin.

In CloudFront, create a distribution, setting the origin domain name to origin.example.com and the Alternate Domain Name for the distribution to www.example.com.

In the settings for each Cache Behavior, ensure that the `Host` header is whitelisted for forwarding to the origin.

Change Route 53's alias for www.example.com to point to your CloudFront distribution.

When requests arrive at CloudFront, the request retains the `Host: www.example.com` header.  CloudFront uses DNS to find the IP address for `origin.example.com` *however*, it only uses this information to make the connection to the origin.  The incoming request is still addressed to www.example.com.  If the origin has an SSL certificate for www.example.com, CloudFront will accept it as valid, because you configured the `Host` header for whitelisting, and it matches the cert.

In this configuration, accessing the CloudFront distribution with the assigned dzczcexample.cloudfront.net hostname in the browser's address bar will not work, because CloudFront will send *that* hostname to the origin, but once you point the Route 53 alias for www.example.com to the assigned cloudfront.net domain name, requests will be processed correctly.